# Sybase ASE Stored Precedure

Tags: stored-procedures, sap-ase

I want to write a Stored Proc which will need to perform below steps

1. Get all the rows from a table where flag= 'Y' and status = != 'PROCESSED'
2. Update rows from step 1 , set status = 'PROCESSED'

I want to do this because this SP will be called every 5 mins from my java program and i do not want to pick the rows which i have already returned from SP thats why i need to mark them processed.

Comment: What is your question?  Remember that requests for code help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.  [Stackoverflow Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Is your issue with the creation of the procedure or the SQL that goes in the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Retrieve the rows you're interested in. Use the holdlock keyword to ensure nothing can sneak in an extra row between the select and the update. The lock is held until the end of the transaction.

The stored procedure performs the retrieval with the shared lock and then upgrades that to exclusive with the update statement.

When the transaction commits the locks are released.

```
create proc update_status as

begin transaction

select *
    from 
        t1 holdlock
    where 
        flag = 'Y' 
    and status != 'PROCESSED'

update t1 set
        status = 'PROCESSED'
    where
        flag = 'Y'
    and status != 'PROCESSED'

commit
go
```